# Spring Boot конфигурация https

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, https, spring-boot, spring-security

При попытке перевести web приложение на Spring Boot  с http на https  столкнулся с интересной ошибкой, а именно:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-01-29 23:49:41.980Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61364', transport: 'socket'
 ERROR 28764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target [Bindable@16951464 type = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties, value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[[empty]]] failed:

Property: server
Value: 
Origin: "server" from property source "class path resource [application.yml]"
Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Облазив все форумы нашел только одно упоминание [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186634/converternotfoundexception-dserver-port-80-noverify-no-converter-found-str)

Но к сожалению отключение или включение быстрой загрузки и вообще удаление зависимости из проекта оказалось бессмысленным.

В чем же проблема?

yml конфиг :

```
server:
     port: 8443
     ssl:
         enabled: true
         key-alias: tomcat-localhost
         key-password: root11
         key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
         key-store-password: root11
         key-store-provider: SUN
         key-store-type: JKS
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился просто до безобразия:

Основной конфиг у меня был в файле application.yml
но стоило переписать его в файл application.properties и все сразу заработало.
properties конфиг :

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat-localhost
server.ssl.key-password=test
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store-password=test
```

Надеюсь кому-то поможет в подобной проблеме

Comment: не должно быть разницы между тем, в каком формате (yaml или properties), у вас конфиг. Возможно, содержимое `application.yml` было невалидно (приведите примеры обоих файлов, если интересно разобраться в проблеме).

Comment: @Nikolay Добавил оба конфига (откатил git и взял yml)

Comment: тоже обратил внимание на то, что Spring при дефолтной конфигурации не умеет читать свойства из .yml (.yaml) файлов. Странно конечно, хотя во всех руководствах говорят об обратном

Answer (score 0):

Проблема yml скорее всего в данной строке

`server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks`

Побробуйте так: `server.ssl.key-store='classpath:keystore.jks'`
или указать полный путь к .jks